# How do I find a non-vacation house to rent in Puerto Rico?

Tags: housing

I'm considering taking some time (6-12 months, probably) to live and work in Puerto Rico (or perhaps Peru, Costa Rica, or Columbia), and one thing I'm having a hard time researching is a rental home for my family.  Most of what I've been able to find on the internet is short-term (rented by the night or week), vacation-oriented, and generally very centrally located in San Juan or a beach city (and therefore expensive).  Where do I find a regular house that isn't spectacular and luxurious, and not in a tourist-y area?

One answer I anticipate is something along the lines of  "you have to go there, speak Spanish, and look in the local newspapers and signs in windows," but that isn't going to help me much here: I need to have a decent idea of what's available *before* I load my family onto a plane to go there, and I speak only enough Spanish to ask for a bathroom.

Comment: So Puerto Rico/Costa Rica/Columbia or Peru?

Comment: I"m interested in Puerto Rico, although any general tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for Rental Properties in Puerto Rico you can probably start with [Ecuentra24](http://www.encuentra24.com/puerto-rico-en/classifieds), [Zillow](http://www.zillow.com/san-juan-pr/#/homes/for_rent/house,condo,apartment,duplex,townhouse_type/1_pnd/days_sort/18.832866,-65.731888,17.839564,-66.591568_rect/9_zm/), or try contacting local real estate agencies like [Ramon Ferreira](http://www.puertoricohomes4sale.com/homes.aspx?tabid=2534764&__ts=1398692322119) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I put "periódicos de Puerto Rico" to Google and got at least a dozen listings of Puerto Rican newspapers.  Went to the classifieds of the first one and found that you can rent a house for anywhere from $400 a month to $8000 a month.  (Nope, no typo there--both prices on the same page.)

I realize that your limited Spanish probably would not allow you to do that, but I'm sure that you can find someone who could do it for you.  In any reasonably sized US city, especially in Texas, you could probably find a Spanish-speaking church with a few members from Puerto Rico.

The Spanish teacher at the nearest public school would likely love to have you visit their class and have the students do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try clasificados.com -   I currently live in Puerto Rico and that’s where I found my house I’m renting. I’m staying in Anasco, which is very near to the beautiful surfing city of Rincon. It is also near to Aguadilla, and all three areas are on the west coast of the island, with wonderful beach is great for snorkeling and surfing depending on the time of year and day